# Android: How to use greenDao for async loading data?

Tags: android, greendao

I would like use greenDao with a **loader <cursor>** to load asynchronously my data from the DB. I found example using loader with a contentProvider. I know that loaders are the best way to load data from a database because it handle the lifecycle of the cursor, auto update the cursor when we add a value.. Unfortunately there is no example of loader with greenDao, is it possible or I have to use a contentProvider??

Thx

Comment: So have you tried that? I have the same idea but not sure

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question since i was also have the same question, but I have an idea but have never tried it yet but you can maybe execute it faster and better than me. I think eventbus(https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) can be a solution, whenever there is a change in the local database (add,delete,update) you can notify an event, and in your activity you should have an event listener that will trigger content reload(re-query again) upon receiving the event.

Answer (score 0):

GreenDao allows you to [run queries and return strongly typed objects](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/), so a loader isn't needed, you can simply wrap it in an ASyncTask. e.g.:

```
    DaoSession session = DbHelper.getInstance().getDaoSession();
    final SpeakerDao speaker = session.getSpeakerDao();

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Speaker>() {

        @Override
        protected Speaker doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return speaker.queryBuilder().list().get(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Speaker result) {
            // do stuff with speaker
        }

    }.execute();
```

Comment: With a loader though, you can be automatically notified of a content change. In this example, wouldn't you have to query in intervals to achieve the same result as the loader?